# Converter um número decimal positivo, em negativo

Tags: mysql, sql, matemática

Tenho a seguinte *query*:

```
Valor1 = '200.000,00';

select Valor1 from TB1
```

Existe alguma função que converte um número positivo para negativo?

Comment: Você quer que mude todos estes valores para negativo direto na tabela? Ou só quer pegar os valores? O que é `Valor1 = '200.000,00';` Isto não parece fazer sentido. è uma *string* mesmo? Porque é *string*? Isto parece ser um valor monetário que precisa fazer cálculos, não deveria ser *string*.

Comment: Eu fiz essa atribuição Valor1 = '200.000,00' para ficar mais didático a minha dúvida. Em relação ao tipo de dado: Isso mesmo bigown esse tipo de dado deveria ser um tipo monetário (decimal), mas é como está hoje na base de dados e eu já peguei o sistema assim. Nessa tabela essa coluna guarda os Valores (tipo string) e quero fazer um select e converter essa string em um numero monetário negatico.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se quiser apenas selecionar os valores como negativos é assim:

```
select -CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Valor1, '.', ''), ',', '.') AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) from TB1
```

ou

```
select -1 * REPLACE(REPLACE(Valor1, '.', ''), ',', '.') from TB1
```

Se quiser mudá-los na tabela:

```
update TB1 set Valor1 = -1 * REPLACE(REPLACE(Valor1, '.', ''), ',', '.')
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/FormatMoney.sql).

Matemática pura, exceto pela conversão. Seria bom repensar se deve usar um tipo que exija conversão. Olha a confusão que terá que fazer em todas consultas. É melhor começar consertar essas coisas para evitar problemas futuros.

Comment: `select -CAST('50.000,00' AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as Valor` 
A query acima me retorna **-50.00** preciso que ele me retorne **50.000,00**... sugestão ??

Comment: Melhorei. Acho que agora está ok.

Comment: @AdrianoCordeiro aconteceu alguma coisa para tirar a aceitação?

Comment: Uma dúvida, não seria melhor o OP tratar como string e fazer a conversão de tipo pra aplicação, ou to falando besteira?

Comment: @DiegoFelipe depende da necessidade dele. É uma possibilidade sim. A pergunta dele não fala em PHP, nem sei se ele usa isto. Na verdade, o melhor é arrumar a estrutura do banco de dados. Claro que isto pode ter implicações na aplicação.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplique por -1 que o resultado da multiplicação é o número negativo.

`select Valor1 * -1 AS Valor1 from TB1`